# Intersection of two conics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots

I'd like to find a closed-form solution for $X,Y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for the following system of equations:

$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}
a + (X - Y) (2 + 5 X - Y) = 0 \\
b X (2 + 5 X) + Y (-2 c (1 + 3 X) + d Y) = 0\end{array}
\right.$$

Using Mathematica, I can get a closed-form, however it's a few hundreds of pages long. My question is whether there is a chance of having a reasonably short expression of the roots. If not, can I get a closed-form approximation of the roots?

Comment: You're looking at the intersection of two curves defined by quadratics; in general, such an intersection may contain as many as 4 points, hence you're probably solving a quartic. That's generally a mess, so you probably can't expect to do a lot better unless your problem has some nice symmetries that are obvious to you but not to Mathematica. Offhand, I don't see any.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thank you. Would it make sense to drop the $X^2$ terms, assuming I'm interested in the intersection of the graphs for $X$ in the vicinity of $0$?

Comment: Moreover, as your equations depend on 4 parameters, there will be many different cases, with 4,3,2,1, 0 roots... But maybe, it could be interesting to know the motivation of you study... because for example knowing the behavior of the curve when it crosses the $y$-axis looks of very limited interest.

Comment: @JeanMarie My motivation comes from classical mechanics. A mechanical system, of known energy $E(X,Y)$, exhibits an instability (bifurcation) when an external force reaches a value. My goal is to have the expression of the "bifurcation point", so that I can study the influence of various parameters. To find the bifurcation point, I first use the fact that equilibrium is a minimum of energy, so a root of both $\partial_X E$ and $\partial_Y E$. The latter happens to be always $0$. The birfucation starts from $Y=0$ which gives $\partial^2_{YX}E=0$.

Comment: [continuation] So in the end I have two equations: $\partial_X E=0$ (equilibrium) and $\partial^2_{YY}E=0$. These are the two equations in the OP. As I said, I'm also interested in approximation (so that I can comment on the physical  relevance of the bifurcation point), but I'm not sure if it makes sense just to do a Taylor series at order 1 in X (or Y) around 0 (assuming X and Y are in the neighbourhood of $0$).

Comment: In the last sentence of [contunation] you say "X AND Y are in the neighbourhood of 0". I think you mean "X OR Y" because, if $a \neq 0$ the fist curve doesn't pass through (0,0).

Comment: I think that your first action is to "drop" some parameters (making some of them constant or zero). Keeping 4 parameters is much too complicated: the behaviors can so completely differ...

Comment: @JeanMarie I can't really drop parameters (the mechanical system has two materials, that's four material properties, 4 dimensions, etc.). I already reduced the number of parameter by a dimensionless analysis. However, I finally found a "solution", see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a general system of equations does not have "short" closed-form solutions, see e.g. John Hughes's comment:

> You're looking at the intersection of two curves defined by
>   quadratics; in general, such an intersection may contain as many as 4
>   points, hence you're probably solving a quartic. That's generally a
>   mess, so you probably can't expect to do a lot better unless your
>   problem has some nice symmetries that are obvious to you but not to
>   Mathematica.

**However**, it might be possible to approximate the solutions in some cases. Considering ranges of values of the parameters such that the system has a solution, and that the solution corresponds to $X$ (or $Y$) sufficiently close from $0$, the second equation can be approximated by a straight line.

To illustrate my point, here (graph below) are the solution curves of the first equation (blue) and second equation (yellow) for $a =b = -1.2$, $c=d=0.3$. Both curves are hyperbolas and one of their intersection is "in the vicinity" of $X=0$ (green dot). Solving the second equation for $Y$, choosing the right solution and approximating it by a first-order Taylor expansion in $X$ in the neighbourhood of $0$ gives: $Y=bX/c$. Solving the first equation for this value of $Y$, i.e. finding the intersection between the blue hyperbola and the red straight line, gives among others the following solution:

$$X_0=\dfrac{(b - c) c + \sqrt{(c- b) c^2 ((-1 + a) b + c - 5 a c)}}{(b - 
   5 c) (b - c)}$$
and $Y_0=bX_0/c$. This gives the red dot below, which is reasonably close from the green dot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The exact intersection is at about $({0.0966, -0.330})$ [green dot] while the approximation is $(0.0864,-0.346)$ [red dot].

Of course, this can only be done for some specific values of $a,b,c,d$, but it's better than nothing.